# Defining optimizer with gradient clipping with tensor flow on Macbook M2 Chip

Tags: tensorflow, data-science, tensorflow2.0, tensor, stock

I am using Macbook with m2, I have install tensorlfow-macos on it. I am trying to run an old code this. In this code I am defining a Define optimizer with gradient clipping. The code is:

```
gradients = tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
clipped, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, clip_margin)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
trained_optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, tf.trainable_variables()))
```

but when I run this code it is giving me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 gradients = tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
      2 clipped, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, clip_margin)
      3 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'trainable_variables'
```

After some research I learnt that some function and methods have been changed in tensorflow 2, so I modified the code to:

```
# Compute gradients
gradients = tf.gradients(loss, tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables())
clipped, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, clip_margin)

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)

# Apply gradients
trained_optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(clipped, tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()))
```

But now when I run this, it gets me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 2
      1 # Compute gradients
----> 2 gradients = tf.gradients(loss, tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables())
      3 clipped, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, clip_margin)
      5 # Define the optimizer

File /Volumes/external hard drive /Source-Codes/tesla-stocks-prediction-master/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:311, in gradients_v2(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
    306 # Creating the gradient graph for control flow mutates Operations.
    307 # _mutation_lock ensures a Session.run call cannot occur between creating and
    308 # mutating new ops.
    309 # pylint: disable=protected-access
    310 with ops.get_default_graph()._mutation_lock():
--> 311   return gradients_util._GradientsHelper(
    312       ys, xs, grad_ys, name, True, gate_gradients,
    313       aggregation_method, stop_gradients,
    314       unconnected_gradients)

File /Volumes/external hard drive /Source-Codes/tesla-stocks-prediction-master/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:480, in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients, src_graph)
    478 """Implementation of gradients()."""
    479 if context.executing_eagerly():
--> 480   raise RuntimeError("tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution "
    481                      "is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.")
    482 ys = variable_utils.convert_variables_to_tensors(_AsList(ys))
    483 xs = [
    484     x.handle if resource_variable_ops.is_resource_variable(x) else x
    485     for x in _AsList(xs)
    486 ]

RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
```

I have tried to install the older version of tensorflow, but failed with that, because I am using m2 Mac, and I didn't found any ways to do it. If someone can help then please.

I tried to define optimizer with gradient clipping for predicting stocks using tensor-flow, but I wasn't able to do so, because I am using a new version tesnorlfow and the project is in tensorlfow 1, I tried making some changes but failed.

Comment: You should use `tf.GradientTape` instead of `tf.gradients`.